# How to write this query without for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three tables with m-to-m relationship. Customer - CustomerCars - Car

I receive a dictionary with a `CustomerId` as a key and an array of his `CarId` as value

```cs
public IDictionary<int,IEnumerable<CarsIdsDto>> Data { get; set; }
```

I want to delete some cars from many customers(`CarsIdsDto` are the Ids of cars that must remain), so my code for this looks like this

```cs
foreach (var entry in message.Data)
{
    var cars = await _context.CustomerCars
        .Where(x => x.CustomerId == entry.Key)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    var newIds = entry.Value.Select(x => x.CarId).ToList();

    //Delete
    var carsToDelete = cars.Where(x => !newIds.Contains(x.CarId));


    await _context.CustomerCars.RemoveRangeAsync(carsToDelete,
        cancellationToken
    );
}
```

The code works fine, but it creates a query for every customer
Can it be refactored to delete all customer cars in one query?

Comment: There's no EF Core code in the question. If `_customerCarsRepository` hides a DbSet then a) that's an ugly **anti**pattern that causes this bug among others and b) using EF Core properly removes the problem. If you have a list of the keys you want to load you can use `_context.Cars.Where(c=>list.Contains(c.Key))`. To get a list of keys from a list of messages you can use `message.Data.SelectMany(entry=>entry.Key)`. What is the actual logic though? Are you trying to delete cars whose `Key` is in the message but `CarId` isn't?  In that case an ORM is probably *not* the best idea.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Each customer has a list of cars. I receive Ids of cars that must remain. For example customer with `Id == 1` has has 3 cars with Ids `{1,2,3}`. I recieve an array of Ids `{1,3}` with key 1 `customerId` ,that means now custmer with `Id == 1` will have only cars with id 1 and 3. Under //Delete I filter those cars that must be deleted. And that must be applied for every customer.